# Running Python in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just downloaded VS Code the other day to use as an IDE for my Python work, but I'm having trouble running a script. I modified my User Settings file with `"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Apps\\Anaconda2\\python.exe"`.

I have a script that just prints "Hello World," and when I click the green arrow at the top of the debug window, I get a message that says `Error File does not exist. ""`

This seems like I'm overlooking something super simple. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What does your `tasks.json` and `launch.json` look like? Can you post it?

Comment: I think I figured out the issue...I had a new file in which I had typed some Python code, but I hadn't actually saved the file as a .py file. Once I do that the issue is solved.

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured out the issue...I had a new file in which I had typed some Python code, but I hadn't actually saved the file as a .py file. Once I do that the issue is solved.